# How to view navigation history in Azure new portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

In Azure new portal how can we view the list of navigation history that we navigated before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, In new Azure portal we have a service called "Recent" (see image below), add it to your favorite menu. It will show all the recently visited resources, just click and navigate to your recently visited resources.

[image: Recent Service]

Answer (score 0):

Vijai, that's a good tip/place to view the navigation history on the Azure Portal.

If you wish, you may review your [Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit)- Through this, you can determine:

- what operations were taken on the resources in your subscription
- who initiated the operation (although operations initiated by a backend service do not return a user as the caller)
- when the operation occurred (in your case WebApps)
- the status of the operation
- the values of other properties that might help you research the operation

The activity log contains all write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE) performed on your resources. It does not include read operations (GET). You can use the audit logs to find an error when troubleshooting or to monitor how a user in your organization modified a resource.

Note: Activity logs are retained for 90 days. You can query for any range of dates, as long as the starting date is not more than 90 days in the past.